# How does ruby-install work?

Tags: ruby, ruby-install

After installation of multiple rubies by [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install), how to use a specific installation of ruby? Should a ruby be accessed by absolute path, or depends on some environment path like `rvm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use postmodern's [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) to change the current Ruby:

```
chruby 1.9
chruby
 * ruby-1.9.3-p429
   ruby-2.0.0-p195
```

It also supports [auto-switching](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#auto-switching) based on a `.ruby-version` file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) which wraps around that to provide an `rvm`-like interface?

Using those directly is not something I'd consider practical.

Comment: Since ruby-install installs rubies into /opt/rubies (root) and ~/.rubies (users) by default, rbenv will not auto-detect rubies previously installed with ruby-install. A better solution is to either use chruby (supports auto-detected /opt/rubies/ and ~/.rubies/) or RVM (recently added support for detect rubies installed into /opt/rubies).

Comment: I wouldn't trust anything that's already been installed. It's better to scrub and rebuild if your Ruby version manager has fallen out of sync.